# mod_wsgi3.4 forbidden permission to access url

Tags: mod-wsgi, wsgi

I’m running apache 2.2.34/mod_wsgi 3.4/ python 2.7.10 on Mac OS X 10.13.1 (17B1003) High Sierra

I’m not using the default apache server. I have stopped that.

LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so in /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

Looks like loading wsgi_module works fine as server is up as I can see this in apache error_log
[Fri Dec 29 21:31:54 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.10 configured -- resuming normal operations

I just single alias mapping to wsgi app, 
WSGIScriptAlias /dk /dkn/gate.py

Issue that I’m facing with /localhost/dk, browser shows permission denied

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /dk on this server.
I can get the /dkn/gate.py as text on browser end.

What is wrong with configuration as I’m stuck as gate.py is facade.

Comment: Would need to see your actual mod_wsgi configuration you added to the Apache configuration file. Also, why are you using mod_wsgi 3.4? That is ancient. I am not even sure how you would get that version compiled for MacOS X High Sierra as Apple don't supply the tools necessary to anymore. You can't just copy the one from Apple Server, if you aren't using Apple Apache httpd, and use it with a different Apache installation.

Comment: I installed mod_wsgi/4.5.22 and still getting the same error.

I have LoadModule and WSGIScriptAlias in httpd.conf.

Comment: LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias /dk /dkn/gate.py

I added above two lines httpd.conf. I couldn’t cut and paste the entire httpd.conf in this comment window.

Comment: LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias /dk /dkn/gate.py

I added above two lines httpd.conf. I couldn’t cut and paste the entire httpd.conf in this comment window.

Comment: Don't need your whole httpd.conf file, but need more than what you show.